# How to define methods: play() and pause() in Vaadin video

Tags: java, vaadin

I created a custom class annotated with @tag('video') in my vaadin application.
Needed attributes like poster, controls, autoplay, src, width etc. have been defined and all working perfectly.
Now I need to define play() and pause() methods for the class, so I could use them programmatically.

Note: the class serves as video like  in html.

```
@Tag("video")
public class Video extends Component implements ClickNotifier{

protected String getVideoSourceAttributeName() {
return VideoAttributes.Source;
}

public void setWidth(String width) {
this.getElement().setAttribute(VideoAttributes.Width, width);
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
this.getElement().setAttribute(VideoAttributes.Height, height);
}

private interface VideoAttributes {
    String Controls = "controls";
    String Source = "src";
    String CurrentTime = "currentTime";
    String AutoPlay = "autoplay";
    String Loop = "loop";
    String Preload = "preload";
    String Poster = "poster";
    String Width = "width";
    String Height = "height";
}


public interface functions {

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case of playing and pausing, there are corresponding methods on the DOM element (inherited from [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#instance_methods)). You can call such methods straight from the server-side `Element` API using the `callJsFunction` method, e.g. `getElement().callJsFunction("play")`.

Comment: O @Leif Astrand, you can believe I'm just seeing this your wonderfully correct answer. Thank you so much. Apparently, I got help with it on discord and just moved on from there. However, thank you again...for this answer is actually correct. It's same as what I got from discord. thanks man!